# Language Fallback not taking effect on my sites

Tags: sxa, multisite, language-fallback

Language fallback not working in Sitecore 9.0 with SXA 1.5.
I have done the below changes to enable language fallback(en) for all added languages.

- On the System Languages in Sitecore Select the language fallback option as "en" for all the languages created.
- Add patches for Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config
    [image]
- Doing the same for sitecore_master_index and sitecore_web_index 
  in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config and Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config respectively.
- Enable the Item Language and Field level fallback checkbox on the template of the item standard values and fields.

Am I missing something? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 2.**
From what I can see you've patched settings for two sites: `shell` and `website`

If your goal is to enable language fallback for SXA sites you have to do the same for them. The difference is that SXA sites definitions are stored in a database, so you have to update items.

1. Find your site definition item: `/sitecore/content/Folder/Tenant/Site/Settings/Site Grouping/S`
2. Extend SXA site attributes

[image]

Comment: I do see the Item level fallback check box here also. Do I need this flag to be selected inside Site Grouping for the Site